# R / Python - Clustering on text data

Tags: python, r, cluster-analysis

I have a set of numbers. My numbers have different formats like `12-12-123-123`, `123-123-123-12`, `123-:12-(123`, `ABC-123-12-123`. The whole data set has around 150 formats. Considering them as strings, is there a way I can group all the numbers falling into specific formats so that given a new number it should check if the new number matches any existing patterns or not. If not it should be able to recommend what is the closest pattern it is to the existing formats.

I can use R or Python.

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: So, I guess you dont want to specify the 150 formats in advance right? Something general would be better? or i.e. is the goal identifying the format or just extracting the number?

Comment: @akrun the output should be like a flag--given a new number if it matches the existing format then YES otherwise NO.

Comment: Not clear about the expected.  Perhaps `patterns <- c("^\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{3}-\\d{3}$", "^\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{2}$", "^\\d{3}-:\\d{2}-\\(\\d{3}$",
     "^[A-Z]{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{3}$"); lapply(patterns, function(x) grep(x, v1))`

Comment: @akrun I do not know the patterns for all the data. And new data comes in all the time and they might have different patterns. So I can not use hard coding. I want to track the old existing ones and create pattern labels so that when a new data comes in I want to see if it matches an existing pattern or not.